# Why socket just dumped between Android and Linux?

Tags: java, android, c++, linux, sockets

In my case,Android App should be regarded as a Server and linux is the client.
I just send data from linux to Android with 4096 bytes per send.
The log shows that linux sends all data successfully.

Here come to the Server, i.e Android...
Server receives data with 4096 bytes per receive. But socket error happened because the read(...) function return the value -1;

Here is my code:

In linux with c++:

```cpp
auto size = static_cast<int>(buffer.size()); // buffer is the data needed to send;
auto bytes_send = 0, bytes = 0;
printf("target. data size needed to send: %d\n", size);

int single = 4096;
while(bytes_send < size){
    int remain = size - bytes_send;
    if(remain < single){
      bytes = send(socket_client_fd, &buffer[bytes_send], remain, 0);
    } else {
      bytes = send(socket_client_fd, &buffer[bytes_send], single, 0);
    }

    if(bytes < 0){
      std::cerr:: "Failed to send data" << std::endl;
      return;
    } 
    bytes_send += bytes;
    printf("This remain: %d; We send %d bytes; Totally %d bytes sended;\n", remain, bytes, bytes_send);

}
```

And the server with java:

```java
   // previously got size need to receive
   byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
   int bytes_recved = 0;
   int single = 4096;
   while(bytes_recved < size){
       int remain = size - bytes_recved;
       int read = -1;
       if(remain < single)
         read = inputStream.read(bytes, bytes_recved , remain);
       else 
         read = inputStream.read(bytes, bytes_recved , single);
       if(read < 0){
         Log.i(TAG, "received failed, less than 0 bytes " + read);
         break;
       }

       bytes_recved += read;
       Log.i(TAG, "received: " + bytes_recved + " ; receive this time: " + read);
   }
```

Client send all data completely, but Server failed to received data, here is the log of Server(Android),It seems that data just lost! I think my code is right, but why it failed?

Here is the log of server:
[The log of Server(Android)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtHbP.png)

Comment: I don't think that you're using the ``off`` (offset) parameter of read. You call this ``readed``. This is an offset into the ``bytes`` array.

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to change that variable to "bytes_recved", I think now is correct after I edit it again.

Comment: BTW you can get rid of the if statement in the Java code by doing: `remain = single`.

Comment: Java naming conventions use camelCase for variables and methods with no underscores. You are using c naming conventions.

Comment: @Tarik Oh! That's great, thanks for your advice. But I still want to know some part of data just lost when read the socket buffer in Android.

Comment: @NomadMaker Thanks for that advice, I'm new to Java. But I still want to know why some part of data just lost! i.e, the read function return value -1.

Answer (score 1):

The logical mistake is this:

```
if(readed < 0)
```

It should be:

```
if(read < 0)
```

I advise you to use better variable names. The past participle of `read` is `read` not `readed`.

Comment: Sorry, It's my fault, I just make a mistake when post this question. I'll re-edit this question

Comment: Can you explain how this "mistake" happened? Did you have some kind of a bug in your computer that corrupted a cut/paste operation?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No clue what you are talking about.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The "mistake" happed Beacuse I write the example code to this website when I post this question. Now in code list is ```c++ if(read < 0 )```,   before re-editing it is  ```c++ if(readed < 0) ```

Comment: Why do you "write the example code" instead of simply cut/pasting the exact code with the issue?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If you are addressing this question to the OP, then put your comment under his question, not my answer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It;s hard to explain, beacause my code is on virtual machine.I cant't cut/pasting it

Comment: In that case there is no way to make sure that the shown code is the actual code that has a problem.